# Magento 2: How to get order data in observer on success page

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer, fatal-error, order-success-page

I'm here **domain.com/checkout/onepage/success/**

Calling my observer on `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
echo $order->getCustomerId()
echo $order->getState()
```

I'm not able to get all information above. How to get?

It gives

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getState() on null

Comment: which event you are calling ? Use sales_order_save_after and you will get status. In checkout_onepage_controller_success_action event , status not available

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` give you order id's

by using `$observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()`.

This **does not given order object directly**  so, you are getting the error

Then you need to object by this id

```
<?php
namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class [ClassName] implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_order;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
    ) {
         $this->_order = $order;    
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
      $orderids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();

        foreach($orderids as $orderid){
            $order = $this->_order->load($orderid);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: how to get all order items & customer info?

Comment: I tried this solution and I received this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Tracy\ShippingMethod\Observer\SendOrderToTracy::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface, none given

Answer (score 2):

Create **events.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="checkout_controller_success_action" instance="VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer\AfterPlaceOrder"  />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create Observer file at **app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Observer/AfterPlaceOrder.php**

```
namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AfterPlaceOrder implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Order Model
     *
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
     */
    protected $order;

     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
    )
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        $order = $this->order->load($orderId);

        //get Order All Item
        $itemCollection = $order->getItemsCollection();
        $customer = $order->getCustomerId(); // using this id you can get customer name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2.1.9 this works for me.

etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Checkout\OnepageControllerSuccessAction" name="vendor_module_observer_checkout_onepagecontrollersuccessaction_checkout_onepage_controller_success_action"/>
</event>
```

Observer\Checkout\OnepageControllerSuccessAction.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Checkout;

class OnepageControllerSuccessAction implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    public function __construct(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $orderids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();

        try {
            foreach ($orderids as $orderid) {
                $order = $this->order->load($orderid);                    
                $order->hold();
                $order->save();
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            // Error logic
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Generic error logic
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't add the logic why the order is placed on hold, but this will get you close to how to modify each of the current orders and saving them.