# Get data from orders with observers

Tags: magento2, product, orders, event-observer

I am with magento 2.3.4,
and I want to capture the information:

> product

> order

> client

I would also like to know how I can print the data on the console.
I am using the observer when ordering
[checkout_onepage_controller_success_action](http://www.marcgento.com/lista-de-eventos-disponibles-para-la-version-2-3-de-magento-2/)

I am trying to capture the information from the observer but nothing shows me

```
<?php
namespace Nasser\Integracion\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class Test implements ObserverInterface{

protected $_logger;
protected $requester;
protected $messageManager;
public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
     \Nasser\Integracion\Helper\Requester $requester,
     \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
)
{
    $this->_logger=$logger;
    $this->requester=$requester;
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
}
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){
 $data = $observer->getEvent()->getData();
 $this->_logger->info('Data', $data);
// $this->messageManager->addNotice(__('Hola este'));
 $erpId = $this->requester->createPedido([]);
}}
```

I hope you can help me

Comment: Check this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/154839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the function `\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success::execute`, you will see the code below:

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
            [
                'order_ids' => [$session->getLastOrderId()],
                'order' => $session->getLastRealOrder()
            ]
        );
```

and therefore, you should be able to log 2 things:

```
$orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order_ids');
 $this->_logger->info('order_id', print_r($orderIds, true));

$order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');
 $this->_logger->info('order', print_r($order->getData(), true));
```

Now, the second line is a big object, so that may be why you see nothing at the moment.. So, I'd start with order increment id for instance.. or just the data you need